# Lumen Daily Logs

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I want to add to my Lumen project a daily Log.

I try this in the app.php (Folder Bootstrap/)

```
$logFile = 'laravel.log';

Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/'.$logFile);
```

But this set me that error

Call to undefined method Monolog\logger::useDailyFiles()

Any help I appreciate...Thanks

Comment: Lumen doesn't have the `Writer` wrapper class with that method available. You'll need to get the Monolog instance, pop off the default handler, and then add your own `RotatingFileHandler`. At least that's how I would do it.

Answer (score 10):

If you look at the framework source code [here](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/4e8af6b6792a212fd7d405469add56a514f100c0/src/Application.php#L410) you can see that it will not do daily logs, but rather write to a single log file `lumen.log`. There is a public method available `configureMonologUsing` seen [here](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/4e8af6b6792a212fd7d405469add56a514f100c0/src/Application.php#L382) and referenced [here](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/4e8af6b6792a212fd7d405469add56a514f100c0/src/Application.php#L366) that you can use to override the default behavior without extending the Application.

Lumen just sets a handler to monolog, so another good solution is you could do this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler;

class LogServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Configure logging on boot.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $maxFiles = 5;

        $handlers[] = (new RotatingFileHandler(storage_path("logs/lumen.log"), $maxFiles))
            ->setFormatter(new LineFormatter(null, null, true, true));

        $this->app['log']->setHandlers($handlers);
    }

    /**
     * Register the log service.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // Log binding already registered in vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php.
    }
}
```

Then don't forget to add the service provider to your Lumen bootstrap/app.php:

```
$app->register(\App\Providers\LogServiceProvider::class);
```

Comment: can we create custom log file?

Comment: @Sreenath what do you mean? Can you be more specific / give more detail?

Comment: I wanted to create log file for each user by his unique id.

Comment: Ah. Hmm. You'll need to make your own custom handler then replace the above code `$handlers[] = ...` with it. You could copy the  [RotatingFileHandler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php) and adjust methods to suit your needs, reading from the current user to create the filenames. You may need to pass in a reference to app in your handler or look into the session or something to get the user.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

In Lumen 5.6 better way is to configure your default setting in .env as `LOG_CHANNEL=daily`

By default the setting is `LOG_CHANNEL=stack` which use single file for logging.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 5.6, configuring the logging system is much easier:

1. Create directory config in your project if it doesn't exist
2. Copy the logging config file from
   vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/logging.php to your project config dir
3. Edit file config/logging.php and adjust the channels property to your liking.

```
    'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['daily'],
    ],
```