# Lumen 5.4 Log info level to separate file

Tags: php, laravel, logging, lumen

Using Lumen Framework 5.4, I am trying to write `Log::info('etc')` into a separate file, `storage/logs/info.log`. However, the code I have found **logs log level info and above** into the seperate file, while I want just the info log level to be logged into my custom file.

In `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) {
    $handler = new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(storage_path('logs/info.log'), Monolog\Logger::INFO, false);
    $handler->setFormatter(new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true));

    $monolog->pushHandler($handler);

    return $monolog;
});
```

How can I make sure that Lumen will log level info into `storage/logs/info.log` and all other log levels into the default log file, `storage/logs/lumen.log`?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/advance-logging-with-laravel-and-monolog

Comment: Your code is correct, you just need to use multiple `StreamHandlers` for different levels of `log`. For demo purpose i have logged `error` & `info` in different files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You Can use multiple `StreamHandlers` for handling different level of
>   log.

**Try this:-** It will log `INFO`in `info.log` file & others in `logs.log` file

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) {

$infoHandler = new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler( storage_path("logs/info.log"), Monolog\Logger::INFO, false);
$noticeHandler = new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler( storage_path("/logs/logs.log"), Monolog\Logger::NOTICE, false);


$monolog->pushHandler($infoHandler);
$monolog->pushHandler($noticeHandler);

$infoHandler->setFormatter(new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true));
$noticeHandler->setFormatter(new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true));

return $monolog;
});
```

**Note:-**

> One note on that snippet, the order you push the streamhandlers on is
>   important: push the most restrictive on last, so that it is hit first.
>   Otherwise, say if you pushed the infoHandler on last, it would
>   log everything above it also and an error wouldn't make it to the
>   error handler.

So push your handlers in Increasing levels of severity

Source:- [Advance Logging with Laravel and Monolog](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/advance-logging-with-laravel-and-monolog)

Answer (score 1):

I had a simliar situation and wanted a seperate log-file for calls to my application done by embedded iframe calls (I provide some widgets to another site)

Found out I was using Lumen version >= 5.6, so I made a custom log channel (By adding logging.php to app/config-dir).

Copied daily channel, and renamed to "widget" along with filename.

Source: [Lumen Daily Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321785/lumen-daily-logs)

In my controller I added

```
use Log;
```

And I log messages like this also in the controller:

```
Log::channel('widget')->info('message from custom channel');
```