# Lumen - Mono Log - Create Custom log file

Tags: php, logging, monolog, lumen-5.2

Currently lumen is writing log to default (lumen.log) file in storage/log.

I want to create custom log file.

Comment: I took reference of this post and resolved my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321785/lumen-daily-logs